# Two of the same application in "open with" option

Tags: 16.04, default-programs, file-properties

When I **right** click a file -> click "Properties" -> click "Open with", there are **two or even more options** of the same application!

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, there are *two* "gedit"'s, *three* "Files", and so on. Is this supposed to happen, are they different, or is this not normal behavior? If it's not supposed to happen how can I fix this?

Comment: This is why serious people use the command line.

Comment: Hi 6EQUJ5, if you open Dash, looking for gedit, do you have two items?

Comment: @JacobVlijm No, I only have one called "Text Editor".
DepressedDaniel I know how to use the command line and open applications. That doesn't mean it's more conveneient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an age-old problem that has been asked and answered many times in the past several years.

Here's an answer [from Unix.SE](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/6675):

> This list gets created by analyzing .desktop files located at:
>
> ```
> /usr/share/applications
> ~/.local/share/applications
> ```
>
> There might be more than one usecase per application, take for example
>   the media player `banshee` which has three .desktop files by default:
>
> ```
> $ ls -1 /usr/share/applications/banshee*
> /usr/share/applications/banshee-1-audiocd.desktop
> /usr/share/applications/banshee-1.desktop
> /usr/share/applications/banshee-1-media-player.desktop
> ```
>
> The only difference between those files is the starting parameter and
>   the MimeType list.
>
> - `banshee-1.desktop`: General media files
> - `banshee-1-audiocd.desktop`: Audio CD's
> - `banshee-1-media-player.desktop` Audio player (Also used by `rhythmbox`, `vlc`, and others)
>
> So we have three 'Banshee Media Player' in the 'Open with' list (and
>   maybe also in the 'Main Menu').
>
> The other way of filling this space is by creating personal .desktop
>   files in `~/.local/share/applications`. Either manually or by using a
>   tool. `alacarte` (or right-click on 'Main Menu' -> 'Edit Menu') is one
>   of those.
>
> Every time you create or move an application within `alacarte`, a new
>   .desktop file gets placed inside `~/.local/share/applications`.
>   Disabling an application will "remove" it from the 'Main Menu', but
>   not from the 'Open with' list.   But the 'Delete' button does, by
>   creating a identical copy from `/usr/share/applications` into
>   `~/.local/share/applications` and adding `Hidden=true` to the .desktop
>   file, thus "overwriting" the system-wide inherited values.
>
> Deleting two of those entries from `alacarte` results in:
>
> ```
> $ ls -1 ~/.local/share/applications/banshee*
> /home/user/.local/share/applications/banshee-1-audiocd.desktop
> /home/user/.local/share/applications/banshee-1-media-player.desktop
> ```
>
> Removing any entries from `~/.local/share/applications` will reverse
>   to the preexisting state (three `banshee` items).
>
> If you really don't have any duplicates in those two folders, try
>   removing any duplicates from `alacarte` or playing with the
>   `Hidden=true` option in the corresponding .desktop files.

Comment: Hold on, it seems the duplicate .desktop files are not only in "/usr/share/applications" and "~/.local/share/applications". After deleting duplicate files I still see some other duplicates in "open with" option. The duplicates are not in those two directories. Are there any other directories? And how do I know which duplicates to delete? It seems like there has to be two nautilus (Files) .desktop files for nautilus to work too. What is alacarte?

Comment: alacarte is a menu editing tool, you can find it using the Ubuntu software app. Regarding the duplicated entries bug, it's so old and difficult to tackle that I ended up accepting it as a fact of life...